# bootstrap/html -- How do I get the mobile slide-down nav to work on desktop resolutions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get the mobile nav style to work on desktop, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm using Bootstrap. I'd like there to be a single 'drop down' button like on mobile that reveals the nav items.

This is what I attempted in HTML, leaving the Bootstrap CSS untouched:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <ol id="toc"></ol>
                    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("ol#toc").tableOfContents($("#content"),
                            { startLevel: "2" } ); 
                        }) 
                    </script>
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show the working example on fiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the class "collapse" from

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

and see how it reacts.

It's possible that data-target needs all classes of a div and not just one, for example:

```
data-target="nav-collapse.collapse"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, no cigar. I basically just want the mobile slide-down nav to also work on desktop. I like its minimalism and compactness!